# Make Terminal Remember last visited folder after closing it on MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am a beginner with the terminal and I don't know to fix this.

I'm working on some projects that are placed in drastically different paths. Because I'm very messy it happens that I close the terminal and then I get a new idea that I would like to try, so I have to open it again and cd into that directory again.
Now I know that tab helps a lot and you can do some workaround with pushd and dirs or aliases but what I want is that whenever I open the terminal it starts from where I was before closing the App.
I noticed that on Simplicity OS that feature is implemented, but I don't know how.

Something similar would be like every time I do  "cd something" automatically the PWD is saved/overwritten in some variable in a hidden file.sh that I can source in the .zshrc so that when I want to go back to the last folder I can just do cd variable.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Terminal has no such feature. Check out iTerm2 (https://iterm2.com/) and its various options for sessions and remembering window arrangements etc. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22445/how-can-i-save-tabs-in-iterm-2-so-they-restore-the-next-time-the-app-is-run. Even there though, if you quit everything, it will start a new session from your home folder, and won't remember last working directories between sessions.

Comment: Stop being so eager to close the session window. If you just quit & relaunch it will stay in the same folder. If you close the session by closing the window it's gone. eg, here are two sessions restored automatically after quit/relaunch [one several times] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/83ptk.png